# C# Blocking collection data handoff time intermittent

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, producer-consumer

Data handoff in blocking collection is taking too much time     sometimes...

Example code:
**Producer:**

```
Blockingcollection<byte[]> collection = new Blockingcollection (5000);
{
    while (condition)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[10240]
        // fill data here.. Read from external source
        collection.add(data);
    }
collection.CompleteAdding();
}
```

**Consumer:**

```
{
    while(!collection.IsCompleteAdding)
    {
        byte[] data = collection.Take();
        // write data to disk..
    }
}
```

Both producer and consumer are running on different task. It runs perfectly but sometime when adding array to collection take around 50 milliseconds which is deal breaker and usually it takes less then 1 millisecond to hand off data. Theoretically the consumer thread should not block when writing as writing to disk is on a separate thread.

Comment: I've tried editing your question but given up quickly. Please edit to valid, compile-able, formatted code.

Answer (score 2):

It's the boundedCapacity value you're passing to the constructor:

```
Blockingcollection<byte[]> collection = 
    new Blockingcollection (5000 /* <--- boundedCapacity */ );
```

You are initializing a blocking collection with a queue limited to 5000 items. When there are 5000 items in the queue, any producer will get blocked until there's an empty slot again. This limit makes sure your queue satisfies [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law). You'll need to analyse your system to get the optimal bound value, or you can leave the queue unbounded and write some unit tests to make sure it doesn't overflow.